# How to implement remember me functionality with php without overwriting session behavior

Tags: php, session, cookies

i have a problem using cookies in my test project, I am trying to implement a remember_me functionality that keeps the user logged in for 30 days if he has clicked the remember me button when logging in and to auto log out him when the browser closes if the button was not clicked during login. Currently i am doing (The connect.php file): The problem is that it currently keeps the user loged in regardless if he has clicked the remember me button

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600 * 24 * 30);
session_start();

//Our MySQL user account.
define('MYSQL_USER', 'root');

//Our MySQL password.
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '');

//The server that MySQL is located on.
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');

//The name of our database.
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'qh_beer_shop');

/**
 * PDO options / configuration details.
 * I'm going to set the error mode to "Exceptions".
 * I'm also going to turn off emulated prepared statements.
 */
$pdoOptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

/**
 * Connect to MySQL and instantiate the PDO object.
 */
$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE, //DSN
    MYSQL_USER, //Username
    MYSQL_PASSWORD, //Password
     $pdoOptions //Options
);
$pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

And the login:

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
$error = '';

try {
//If the POST var "register" exists (our submit button), then we can
//assume that the user has submitted the registration form.
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //Retrieve the field values from our registration form.
        // $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
        // $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;


//Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.
        $sql = "SELECT 
                id AS id,
                username AS username,
                password AS password,
                email AS email,
                phone AS phone,
                address AS address,
                first_name AS first_name,
                last_name AS last_name,
                age AS age             
            FROM
                users
            WHERE
                 username = ?
             ";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);


        $stmt->execute([$username]);



        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        $passwordHash = $user['password'];
        if (!password_verify($password, $passwordHash)) {
            setcookie('remember_me', '', time() - 100000);
            throw new Exception("Wrong username or password!");
        }

        $hour = time() + 3600;
        setcookie('ID_my_site', $_POST['username'], $hour);

        if($_POST['remember']) {
            $month = time() + 3600 * 24 * 30;
            setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $month);
        }
        elseif(!$_POST['remember']) {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) {
                $past = time() - 100;
                setcookie('remember_me', '', $past);
            }
        }




        $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user['username'];
        header('Location: profile.php');

    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $error = $exception->getMessage();
}
```

?>

Comment: Check with https://pastebin.com/hqeynqXS - Made modifications. Haven't tested tho.

Comment: it says localhost is redirecting me too many times when i open login.php.

Comment: What file is the code of - https://pastebin.com/hqeynqXS - for ?

Comment: It is for the login.php file

Comment: Can you pastebin HTML code for logging in?

Comment: And for profile.php as well?

Comment: I will in 30 minutes, thanks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/q9bntYNZ - html for login
https://pastebin.com/1JE67TGr - profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167861/discussion-between-karlo-kokkak-and-twinaxe96).